# Right margin seaborn joint plot disappears when adding regression line

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Using the tips I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947656/combine-two-seaborn-plots), I'm able to put a regression line on top of a seaborn jointplot.

The following snippet creates the plot below:

**Code 1**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

# Generate a random correlated bivariate dataset
rs = np.random.RandomState(5)
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x1, x2 = rs.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T
x1 = pd.Series(x1, name="$X_1$")
x2 = pd.Series(x2, name="$X_2$")

# Show the joint distribution using kernel density estimation
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0)
sns.regplot(x1,x2, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
```

**Plot 1a**

[image]

Adding `sns.regplot(x1,x2, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)` to the mix will render this plot:

**Plot 1b**

[image]

And that is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

However, when I'm using the same code on some real world data, I'm getting some really weird results with regards to the **distribution plot in the right margin**. Let's just call the two series A and B.

**Code 2**:

```
A = pd.Series([2197.0,2207.0,2016.0,1993.0,2126.0,2507.0,3123.0,3632.0,3504.0,3515.0,3394.0,3222.0,3167.0,3071.0,2847.0,2776.0,2878.0,2946.0,3051.0,3021.0,2983.0,3044.0,2951.0,2781.0,2434.0])
B = pd.Series([34.0,159.0,-48.0,-134.0,-229.0,-73.0,31.0,-65.0,261.0,616.0,481.0,544.0,360.0,414.0,359.0,142.0,117.0,173.0,115.0,-36.0,-15.0,105.0,316.0,-30.0,-137.0])
g = sns.jointplot(A, B, kind="kde", size=7, space=0)
sns.regplot(A,B, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
```

**Plot 2**

[image]

I think this is pretty strange in itself, bacuse there's nothing about the properties of the B series that could explain this result. You can verify this by changing the order of the series like this:

**Code 3**:

```
g = sns.jointplot(B, A, kind="kde", size=7, space=0)
sns.regplot(B, A, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
```

**Plot 3**:

[image]

As you can see, it's still the distribution plot in the right margin that's the problem here, and not the data in itself. And just to double check, you can see that you would still get the correct margin plots by commenting out `sns.regplot(B, A, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)` and running it again:

**Code 4:**

```
g = sns.jointplot(B, A, kind="kde", size=7, space=0)
# sns.regplot(B, A, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
```

**Plot 4:**

[image]

Strange, right? But it get's even stranger if you run the whole thing again, but this time replace `kind = 'kde'` to `kind = 'reg'`.

**Code 5:**

```
g = sns.jointplot(B, A, kind="reg", size=7, space=0)
sns.regplot(B, A, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
```

**Plot 5:**

[image]

As you can see, now the right margin plot is exactly where it's supposed to be.
I've been messing around with other possible solutions as well, but these are the ones that I think most clearly shows the weirdness of the problem. So, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

**System info:**

Windows 7, 64 bit

Python 3.6.0

Matplotlib 2.0.0

Seaborn 0.7.1

IPython 5.1.0

Comment: Can you update your question with the versions of packages you are using? Your code 2 and code 3 works on my machine

Comment: Sure, and thank you for having a look at this!

Comment: With seaborn 0.8.1 and matplotlib 2,1.2 I cannot reproduce the problem you have with code 2 and 3 (just like DavidG). I would suggest upgrading to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm going to try that right now.

Comment: Updated to seaborn 0.8.1 and now it works (still on matplotlib 2.0.0 though due to some issues with conda. Or so I think...). Would any of you who suggested this solution like to write it up as an answer?